# send data using controller in app.blade laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a `UserController` and i want to send data from `UserController` function to `app.blade.php`.

```
function sessionUser(){
        $data['status'] = Auth::user()->status;
        $data['id'] = Auth::id();
        $data['values]=DB::table('user_permission)->get();
        return view('app.blade', compact('data'));
    }
```

and in app.blade.php

```
dd($data);
```

Comment: just use return view('app', compact('data')); it will automatically check for blade.php file

Comment: i use it already but it shows unknown $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
function sessionUser(){
    $data['status'] = Auth::user()->status;
    $data['id'] = Auth::id();
    $data['values']=DB::table('user_permission')->get();
    return view('app')->with($data);
}
```

Or

```
function sessionUser(){
    $status = Auth::user()->status;
    $id = Auth::id();
    $values = DB::table('user_permission')->get();
    return view('app', compact('status','id','values'));
}
```

Then `echo dd($status);`